# How to identify public controllers in swagger doc with .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, swagger

I'm working on documenting my NET Core web API and integrating it with Swagger.
I have a controller which has two methods, one public (GetEmpresas) and one that requires authorization (GetEmpresa) with JWT Token, as you can see in the **[Authorize]** Tag:

```
[Route("OhmioApi/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class ActivityController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IEmpresasService service;

    public ActivityController(ISecurityService securityService, IEmpresasService service, IMapper mapper)
        : base(securityService, mapper)
    {
        this.service = service;            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtener listado de Empresas disponibles para el cliente ID
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks>Metodo público sin TOKEN</remarks>                    
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<EmpresasBase_model>))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmpresas([FromQuery][Required] string clientId)
    {
        var empresas = await service.GetEmpresas(clientId);

        return new ObjectResult(empresas);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtener los detalles de una empresa
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks>Metodo privado con TOKEN</remarks>            
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("{empresaId}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(Empresas_model))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmpresa([FromRoute][Required] string empresaId)
    {
        var empresa = await service.GetEmpresa(empresaId);

        return new ObjectResult(empresa);
    }
}
```

Now on Swagger both endpoints appear as secured (with the padlock):

[image]

**So my question is how can I tell to swagger which endpoints require authorization and which don't?**

Comment: This seems to be by design and there's a similar conversation here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4402

Comment: This IOperationFilter may help but I'm not sure how the UI renders it: https://skalinets.github.io/swagger-authorization.html

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it